# Darkseid's Omega Beam vs Superman's heat-vision

Tags: dc, superman, dc-animated-universe

They've battled a few times as far as I know, but have their beams ever directly collided?

And if so, who came out on top?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Supperman the dinner hero?

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro lol, thanks.

Comment: Any beam that can arbitrarily bend and chase people will always beat a line of vision beam.

Comment: @cde Really? How do you know this?

Comment: Because simple logic? Your question is obviously about raw power, but seriously, comparing two weapons where one is crippled by line of sight compared to one that can bend around corners...

Comment: @cde _Because simple logic?_ they're shooting lasers from their eyes... Logic has no place here.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Doomsday has been hit by the full force of both, and heat vision did more initial damage than the full Omega Force.

Comment: @Monty129 actually I think you're correct. I remember Superman lobotomising Doomsday with his heat vision.

Comment: Do you mean in the current DC continuity (New 52!) or in the past?

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza I actually wasn't aware they had battled in the New 52. But I'll accept either continuity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [Adventures Of Superman 595](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Adventures_of_Superman_Vol_1_595), Superman and Darkseid fight on Apokolips. Their beams meet briefly at point-blank range during this fight and appear evenly matched. (The fight itself is interrupted by Brainiac-13.)

[image: Darkseid vs Superman]

Comment: This is a great answer, cheers!

Answer (score 6):

They collided here in Superman v Darkseid Apokolips Now in the Post Crisis era.

[image: Superman v Darkseid Apokolips Now 1]

However New 52 Darkseid's Omega beams have been shown to destroy planets, Superman's heat vision isn't remotely as powerful.